# Dividing a Matrix into three parts

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix $A$ is given by $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

Given that $A^3$ can be expressed as $A^3$=$aA^2+bA+cI$, find the values of $a,b,c$. Furthermore, express the inverse $A^{-1}$ in the form $A^{-1}$=$dA^2+eA+fI$, where $d$,$e$, and $f$ are rational numbers

I was given this problem in a homework set and did not make much progress. I'm not sure as to how I should separate matrix $A$ into three components.

Comment: Have you learned how to find the eigenvalues and the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Comment: Just calculate $A^3$, $A^2$ respectively first. Then multiply the coefficient (i.e. a/b/c) into  $A^2$ , $A$, $I$  respectively. Then do the addition work.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but it seems kind of bashy since there were so many calculations. I was looking for a more elegant method using elementary knowledge

Answer (score 2):

Calculating $\det(A-\lambda I)=\det\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda&2&1\\1&1-\lambda&2\\2&3&1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ gives

$\hspace{.3 in}(1-\lambda)^3+11-10(1-\lambda)=-(\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-7\lambda-2)$,

so by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $\;\;A^3-3A^2-7A-2I=0$

and therefore $\;\;A\big[\frac{1}{2}(A^2-3A-7I)\big]=I$.

---

Alternatively, using the idea suggested by hkmather802,  we can find $A^2$ and $A^3$ to get the equation

$\begin{pmatrix}24&35&25\\25&36&29\\35&51&36\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}5&7&6\\6&9&5\\7&10&9\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}1&2&1\\1&1&2\\2&3&1\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Just using the first row, we get the linear system

$5a+b+c=24,\;\;7a+2b=35,\;\;6a+b=25$;

so solving the last two equations gives $a=3, b=7$; and substituting in the 1st equation gives $c=2$.

Comment: Assuming that I did not have prior knowledge of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, would there be another way to solve this with more elementary methods?

Comment: I will edit my answer to give another way.